# Cutting off everything

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Left alone, I am very bad for youse.
>   Right here, below are certain clues.
>
> Take an axe and cut off my head
>   Oh, such a nasty term for a woman?
>
> From the rest, drop the other end
>   I almost become a huge bend.
>
> From the remaining, drop my rear
>   You are abusing me? Oh Dear!
>
> From what is left, take off my crown
>   It's your with a deep, grave frown
>
> Now, cut off my tail,
>   Oh, my identity has changed!

**So, What Am I?**

Comment: Whoever downvoted, kindly spare a comment on how to improve the post..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> scurvy

making the words

> curvy (which I'd have thought quite a complimentary term for a woman, on the whole), curv (curve without its last letter), cur (a term of abuse, literally meaning a dog), ur (not sure *exactly* why this is "your with a deep, grave frown" but it's clearly in the right ballpark; perhaps the frown is of disapproval at such txtspk), and u (from I to You...).

In more detail, at Sid's request:

Left alone, I am very bad for youse.
Right here, below are certain clues.

> We begin with the word SCURVY, the name of a disease that's very bad for you.

Take an axe and cut off my head
Oh, such a nasty term for a woman?

> Now (S)CURVY. If you call a woman "curvy" it generally means she is pleasingly plump, but you be be suspected of just wanting to call her fat with plausible deniability.

From the rest, drop the other end
I almost become a huge bend.

> CURV(Y). "Curve" with one letter missing.

From the remaining, drop my rear
You are abusing me? Oh Dear!

> CUR(V). A cur is literally a dog, but it's usually used (when it's used at all) as a term of abuse for a human being.

From what is left, take off my crown
It's your with a deep, grave frown

> (C)UR. "Ur" is txtspk for "your". Sid has indicated in comments that the "grave, deep frown" was just there for metre and rhyme and therefore doesn't need explaining.

Now, cut off my tail,
Oh, my identity has changed!

> U(R). "U" is txtspk for "you". This riddle started out being about "I", so that's something of a change.

Comment: yeah this is probably right

Comment: Correct! A few clarifications though- I meant curvy as derogatory because it is sometimes used to refer women to be fat. Frown was used just for rhymes and your sounds like U R

Comment: Try to explain each line of the riddle please... now that you have gotten the final answer. It makes it easy to read...

Comment: Oh, I think it makes it tiring to read because you end up with a billion separate spoiler blocks. But OK, I'll do that.